# Django, Factory boy - can't create subfactory

Tags: django, django-testing, factory-boy

I have created three factories where User and Profile are associated as onetoone field, also Label is sub factory of Profile.

```
import factory
from users.models import User, Label, Profile
from .models import Release
import random
from django.db.models.signals import post_save


@factory.django.mute_signals(post_save)
class ProfileFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile

    user = factory.SubFactory("releases.factories.UserFactory", profile=None)


@factory.django.mute_signals(post_save)
class UserFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = User

    email = factory.Faker("email")
    password = factory.Faker("password")

    profile = factory.RelatedFactory(ProfileFactory, factory_related_name='user')


class LabelFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    profile = factory.SubFactory(ProfileFactory)
    name = factory.Faker("name")

    class Meta:
        model = Label
```

but when I try to create a label (LabelFactory.create()) it throws the error

```
RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: User has no profile.
```

What is wrong? Please help!

Comment: Why was `profile=None` set in `ProfileFactory`'s user? Is it because of the related factory in `UserFactory`?

Comment: https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/recipes.html#:~:text=UserFactory%27%2C%20profile%3DNone)-,%40factory.django.mute_signals(post_save),-class%20UserFactory(factory . Yes

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem
to create a label first you need to create a profile

```
profile = ProfileFactory.create()
```

and then create a label like this

```
label = LabelFactory(profile=profile)
```

if you want to create a factory related to both

```
release = ReleaseFactory(profile=profile, label=label)
```